# Converting a python lookahead assertion regex to valid Golang

Tags: python, regex, go

I have the following regex that works well in Python (due to lookahead assertions).

`some_list = re.findall('^(?=Name:)(.*?)(?=USB\ Device\ Filters:)', myinput, re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)`

See example of `myinput` in the code block below.

*Name:* will always be the beginning of a group and *USB Device Filters:* will always be the end of a group. Not all lines have a valid key:value, e.g., can have  or a blank line.

```
Name:            Server1 10.0.0.11
Groups:          /
Guest OS:        Ubuntu (64-bit)
\n
<none>
USB Device Filters:

Name:            Server2 10.0.0.12
Groups:          /
Guest OS:        Debian (64-bit)
\n
<none>
USB Device Filters:
```

Can anyone help me convert this into a valid **Golang** regex?

The ultimate goal is to parse myinput and get a slice of matched groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given this in Python:

```
^(?=Name:)(.*?)(?=USB Device Filters:)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fhVrjJ/1/)

Since `^(?=Name:)` is a zero width assertion, `Name:` is captured by the capturing groups following it.

You can capture the same in Golang with this:

```
^(Name:.*?)USB Device Filters:
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hyZzMF/2/)

If you don't want to capture `Name:\s` you can do:

```
^Name:\s*(.*?)USB Device Filters:
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ePWpbV/1/)

You don't need to escape the spaces with `(?=USB\ Device\ Filters:)` in either language. All have `(?ms)` flags set.

Comment: Thanks @dawg. This got me on the right track. I must have blanked out last night and forgot about the flags. This worked for me in the end... ```regexp.MustCompile(`(?ms)^(Name:.*?)USB Device Filters:`)```